# Django passing data from one app to another?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using `django-allauth` for my authentication. I have a dashboard which has many links.

**user.html**

```
`{% include 'sidebar.html' %}
 <h1>Profile View</h1>
 <p>{{ profile.username }}</p>`
```

**change_password.html**

```
`{% include 'sidebar.html' %}
 <h2>Change Password</h2>
 <p>{{ profile.username }}</p>`
```

**sidebar.html**

```
`<a href="{% url 'profile_view' slug=profile.username %}">Profile View</a>
 <a href="{% url 'change_password' %}">Change Password</a>`
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = "user.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    slug_field = "username"
```

**change password** view is from django-allauth. How can i pass the the username from the `ProfileView` to the change password view so that i can display in the `change_password.html` page.

**Main Problem**
Since i have been including `sidebar.html` to both the views, it works good in `ProfileView` but when i navigate to `change_password` view i get the following error

> Reverse for 'profile_view' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-\w.@+-]+)/$']

the error does not show in `ProfileView` because the `profile.username` returns a value, but when i navigate to `change_password` view i get the above error because the `profile` context object only passes in that particular view. i want to use that context_object through out the project.

Is there a simple way to do it? other than build a JSON API?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look at the template tags provided by the allauth app. I haven't tested this (nor do I use the project) but this looks like what you are looking for.

In your template, any template...

```
{% load account %} {# this should be near the top with any other load tags #}

{# this can be anywhere in the template. I'm not positive what it returns but it looks like it is the username. #}
<p>
    {% user_display user %}
</p>
```

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/templatetags/account.py).

Comment: nope! that is not what i was looking.. is there any other way to do it? possible to write something from scratch

Comment: Hey @Rahul, I'm not sure what django-allauth is doing but typically the user information is available to every view via `{{ user }}` or `{{ request.user }}`. Do either of those work? If not, then django-allauth is doing something to the middleware there. In that case you could write a Custom Template Tag to get the username from allauth. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: If you would like a hand with that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, Thank you @teewuane

sidebar.html

`<a href="{% url 'profile_view' slug=profile.username %}">Profile View</a>`

replaced as

`<a href="{% url 'profile_view' slug=request.user.username %}">Profile View</a>`